Keycloak on /login page - Angular
Is it possible to make it so that when the user opens localhost:4200, it opens the home page, and when he clicks on the login button and is redirected to localhost:4200/login, then the keyclock opens and after a successful login, it returns to the home page again?
My code so far:
app.module.ts:
export function initializeKeycloak(keycloak: KeycloakService) {
  return () =>
    keycloak.init({
      config: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8080',
        realm: 'iit',
        clientId: 'iit-user',
      },
      initOptions: {
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
          window.location.origin + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',
      },
    });
}

silent-check-sso.html
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
      parent.postMessage(location.href, location.origin);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

And on keycloak page, valid redirect URI is: http://localhost:4200/*

In config you specify wrong port? What's the error that you face?

I don't have an error. Keycloak works on localhost:4200/, but I want it on localhost:4200/login. If I change valid redirect URI to localhost:4200/login, it works on /login, but on localhost:4200 I get: Invalid parameter: redirect_uri. Port is fine, my keycloak is on localhost:8080.

@Valerija I am not clear with your question. From your above comment, i guess you can give a try by changing Valid Redirect URI to *.
